# Position the center of a div on a coordinate

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am making an tool with which people can keep track of plants in their garden and borders. This is a bit of a hobby project with the additional goal to get my programming skills up to date after 15 years of inactivity (last project I did ended ugly because if IE 5.0 vs 5.5 issues, to get the timescale).

Anyway, in this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4yfp.png) picture you see a label in the editor. The text within it is different for each label, which makes the width variable. The two tiny icons to the side are taken off in the client view, which makes the width even more unpredictable. How do I keep the labels on the same spot on the map?

I used to use the left and top coordinates and some +/- pixels to deal with the position, but that doesn't work very well. So I managed to get the center coordinates of the labels into my database with this function (this is just the x coordinate, but you get the drift):

```
var rect    = map.getBoundingClientRect();
var circ    = pin.getBoundingClientRect();
var x       = ( circ.left + circ.width / 2 )  - rect.left;    
return  Math.round(x);
```

However, I am not sure how to deal with the positioning when I create the html of the map from the database with PHP. I have a few directions drifting in my mind, all of them a bit hacky, but I hope you can help me with something that works without cutting corners.

This is the line of PHP code that deals with the position of the label. Style:left and top are obviously not the right choices any more:

```
$html = "<div class='xyz' style='left:".$loc_x."px; top:".$loc_y."px;'>\n";
```

This is the css of the div, in case its relevant. I use the drag lib from jQuery which adds position: absolute, I think.

```
.xyz{

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas:  "move write menu";
    background: rgba(var(--popupLight),1);
    border: 2px solid rgba(var(--popupBorder),1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px grey;
```

}

What is the best way to get the proper coordinates of positioning in this scheme?
Thanks in advance!

Diederik, Westzaan, The Netherlands

Comment: _“Style:left and top are obviously not the right choices any more”_ - but neither would right and/or bottom be, and there isn’t anything else regarding absolute positioning. You should try and work with a combination of positioning the top/left edge, and then offsetting the element against that using a `translate` transformation.

Comment: O, I was a bit vague. I bet I can find the right offset in Javascript. I wonder whats the best way to call js function doesTheTrick() and let in infuse its magic into the php line above.
Assuming there is no way to deal with this with clever CSS.

Comment: _“Assuming there is no way to deal with this with clever CSS.”_ - can’t answer that, because we know way too little about the actual setup so far, the code snippets you have shown above don’t paint a complete picture. Questions like this should start with a proper [mre] that shows what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: OK, I will make a demo!

Comment: Alright. 
Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/dcslob/pen/GRrOVbx 
Lets assume I want to place the center of the pin (id=9) at x=250 and y=300 on the map (id= bordermap). Let's stick with manipulating the x, that's the important one.

Comment: Your box is 600px wide there, so if you position the marker absolute at `left: 300px`, and then add `transform: translateX(-50%);`, it should be nicely centered in the horizontal.

Comment: I tried a few options, and decided that pure css wasn't going to cut it. I made a javascript function that is called after the page is built and centers all the divs on their coordinates. Works like a charm.